# using chef-server-ctl sql to modify node permissions

Tags: chef-infra

Sometimes chef client nodes cannot update the chef server and the permissions need be changed.

Since I'm not allowed to enable the Web GUI, is there a way to do it with

***chef-server-ctl sql*** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [knife-acl](https://github.com/chef/knife-acl) plugin to modify the ACLs using `knife acl` on your workstations.

Comment: Close. This deals with user permissions and not so much with client permissions.

Comment: Sure? I haven't actively used it, but expect it to work. The README also explains a `MEMBER_TYPE` that can be  `client` / `group` / `user`.

Comment: Indeed, clients and users are indistinguishable to the ACL system.